# How to create a job in SQL Server to insert into a table from a view

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will insert data stored in a view in a table.

I used this script :

```
use SVC_DWH
Go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

INSERT INTO DWH_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE
    SELECT * 
    FROM TD_Importation_Kit_Production_Vente_VH
```

The problem is that my table is underlined and it tells me that there no invalid object name like that even though my database contains that table.

Comment: There isn't any data stored in a view. Is a `DWH_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE`  a view or table?

Comment: Maybe it's in a different schema? What happens if you fully qualify the name?

Comment: @Jason  There's data stored in the view and DWH_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE is a table

Comment: It worked ! I had just to restart my sql server management studio

Comment: Then it sounds like you needed to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R` in SSMS. That refreshes any schema change. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/04/sql-server-how-to-refresh-ssms-intellisense-cache-to-update-schema-changes/

Comment: Exactly what i needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use exactly columns name to insert

```
INSERT INTO DWH_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE
VALUES([Field1],[Field2],[Field3],...)
SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],... 
FROM TD_Importation_Kit_Production_Vente_VH
```